# Как спарсить данные по одному элементу Python

Tags: python, парсер

Вот сайт https://smart-lab.ru/q/portfolio/dr-mart/10628/
Как мне можно оттуда спарсить нужную для меня строку в таблице, где акции?

Comment: Какие конкретно данные? Давайте разметку. Так никто ниче делать не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот быстрый пример для таблицы "Российские акции" строка №1

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://smart-lab.ru/q/portfolio/dr-mart/10628/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

data = tree.xpath('//table[@csv-download-data="russian_shares"]//tr[2]/td/text()')
company_name = tree.xpath('//table[@csv-download-data="russian_shares"]//tr[2]//a/text()')
```